# How to change header background color of Dynamic Table Report of gotreportviewer programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0, report-viewer2010

I am using gotreportviewer's Dynamic Table report to generate reports.

Here we will be populating data in the dataset and generate dynamically.

I would like to know how to change Report Column(Header) background color programmatically.

Comment: When you say want to change it programatically is it a fixed background color to all headers or do you have some logic for each header to have a specific color

Comment: Only one color for all headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the below code in TableRdlGenerator.cs (line 110)

```
private Rdl.StyleType CreateHeaderTableCellTextboxStyle()
        {
            Rdl.StyleType headerTableCellTextboxStyle = new Rdl.StyleType();
            headerTableCellTextboxStyle.Items = new object[]
                {
                    "700",
                    "14pt"
                };
            headerTableCellTextboxStyle.ItemsElementName = new Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5[]
                {
                    Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5.FontWeight,
                    Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5.FontSize
                };
            return headerTableCellTextboxStyle;
        }
```

with

```
private Rdl.StyleType CreateHeaderTableCellTextboxStyle()
        {
            Rdl.StyleType headerTableCellTextboxStyle = new Rdl.StyleType();
            headerTableCellTextboxStyle.Items = new object[]
                {
                    "700",
                    "14pt",
                    Color.Black
                };
            headerTableCellTextboxStyle.ItemsElementName = new Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5[]
                {
                    Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5.FontWeight,
                    Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5.FontSize,
                    Rdl.ItemsChoiceType5.BackgroundColor,
                };
            return headerTableCellTextboxStyle;
        }
```